# Average Multiple Columns in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with multiple rows, each of which contains these four columns:

| product | price_instore | price_pickup | price_delivery | price_ship |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $13.00 | $13.50 | $14.50 | $18.00. |
| 2 | $4.00 | $4.00 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | $10.00 | $10.00 | $12.00 | NULL |

I'd like to have a fifth column average_price that gives the average price for a product, but does not count NULLS towards the sum price, or towards the count used to divide the average.

So average price of product 1: ($13+$13.50+$14.50+$18)/4=$14.75 
Average price of product 2: ($4+$4)/2 = $4.00 
Average price of product 3: ($10+$10+$12)/3 = $10.67

Is there any way to do this is SQL? I've tried subqueries such as the one below without success:

```
(select coalesce((PRICE_INSTORE + PRICE_PICKUP + PRICE_DELIVERY + PRICE_SHIP) / 4, 
PRICE_INSTORE, PRICE_PICKUP, PRICE_DELIVERY, PRICE_SHIP)
```

but then I only get one price if any of them are null

Comment: Why not coalesce each of the four columns instead of their sum?

Comment: So SELECT AVERAGE((COALESCE( PRICE_INSTORE)+COALESCE(PRICE_PICKUP)+COALESCE(PRICE_DELIVERY)+COALESCE(PRICE_SHIP) ? @JohnnyFitz

Comment: yes think so but use coalesce(col name,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  select coalesce (PRICE_INSTORE, 0 ) +  coalesce (PRICE_PICKUP, 0) + coalesce (PRICE_DELIVERY , 0) + coalesce (PRICE_SHIP , 0)  / 
 ((case when PRICE_INSTORE is null then 0 else 1 end) + (case when PRICE_PICKUP is null then 0 else 1 end) +
 (case when PRICE_DELIVERY is null then 0 else 1 end) + (case when PRICE_SHIP is null then 0 else 1 end) )
 from product
```

Comment: Do you know that anything = null is always null? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cfcd84d43636ca815efbdce20a38061d Should be `... is null`

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    *,
    (select avg(x) from unnest(array[price_instore,price_pickup,price_delivery,price_ship]) as x) as avg_price
from
   your_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm drunk, so there's probably a much better way to do this than pivoting, but I cannot see it now with the room spinning around me like it is.

```
with j as (
  select product, to_jsonb(mytable) - 'product' as jdata
    from mytable
)
select j.product, avg(e.value::numeric) as avg_price
  from j
       cross join lateral jsonb_each(j.jdata) as e(key, value)
 where e.value is not null
 group by j.product.
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is a lateral join:

```
select t.*, avg_price
from t cross join lateral
     (select avg(price) as avg_price
      from (values (price_instore), (price_pickup), (price_delivery), (price_ship)
           ) v(price)
     ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   select coalesce(PRICE_INSTORE,0) + coalesce(PRICE_PICKUP,0) + coalesce(PRICE_DELIVERY,0) + coalesce(PRICE_SHIP,0)) / 4
```

Comment: The only issue I see with this one is the hardcoded "4" - I want the average of available prices, so for example if shipping unavailable I'd divide by 3. That's the problem I kept running into with my attempts

Comment: @ClintonSorrel as you have probably seen by now you could use a Case statement as described in Mukhtiar's answer above with case when PRICE_DELIVERY is null then 0 else 1 end.

Answer (score 1):

This one is probably the easiest to digest. Performance shouldn't be too bad unless you have a very large table that is also, not indexed

```
 with cte (product, prices) as 
  
(select product, price_instore from t union all
 select product, price_pickup from t union all
 select product, price_delivery from t union all
 select product, price_ship from t)
  
select product, avg(prices)
from cte
group by product;
```

You an either use the output as is, or wrap it around another CTE and use that to join on your original table to get the averages